# Пропадает текст в карусели

Tags: bootstrap, carousel

В карусели бутстрапа на слайде расположен див с текстом. Все работает, скрипт считывается. Ширина дива с текстом 50%. При адаптиве все тоже работает. Но при ширине экрана меньше 770рх див исчезает. Он не съезжает вниз, он просто исчезает весь. Слайды продолжают меняться. Пробовала уменьшать размер дива и размер текста (чтоб его найти). Не помогло. 
ПОМОГИТЕ))) Куда мог деться див?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Зоя так это же естественно, bootstrap при размере меньше ширины монитора автоматически убирает текст. Как же вы разглядите текст на телефоне? Или вы специально без bootstrap добавляете div?

Comment: Спасибо. Мне уже помогли на другом сайте.